# I need help to convert vcxproj to cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, vcxproj

There is Visual Studio 2015 project. I need to compile it for Debian. I am trying to convert it to makefile using vcxproj2cmake. Firstly I want to compile it on Windows.

`perl vcxproj2cmake.pl project1.vcxproj "\Debug|Win32"` generated file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

## section: Macro
MACRO(ADD_MSVC_PRECOMPILED_HEADER PrecompiledHeader PrecompiledSource SourcesVar)
  IF(MSVC)
    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(PrecompiledBasename ${PrecompiledHeader} NAME_WE)
    SET(PrecompiledBinary "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PrecompiledBasename}.pch")
    SET(Sources ${${SourcesVar}})

    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${PrecompiledSource}
                                PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yc\"${PrecompiledHeader}\" /Fp\"${PrecompiledBinary}\""
                                           OBJECT_OUTPUTS "${PrecompiledBinary}")
    SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${Sources}
                                PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/Yu\"${PrecompiledBinary}\" /FI\"${PrecompiledBinary}\" /Fp\"${PrecompiledBinary}\""
                                           OBJECT_DEPENDS "${PrecompiledBinary}")  
    # Add precompiled header to SourcesVar
    LIST(APPEND ${SourcesVar} ${PrecompiledSource})
  ENDIF(MSVC)
ENDMACRO(ADD_MSVC_PRECOMPILED_HEADER)

## start setting
SET (this_target project1)
PROJECT(${this_target})



## section: include directory
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  $(BOOST_INCLUDE)
    $(OPENSSL)/include
    $(ZLIB_INCLUDE)
    ./..
  )

## section: source files
# Add your source files here (one file per line), please SORT in alphabetical order for future maintenance
SET (${this_target}_SOURCE_FILES
#   ...
    )

## section: header files
# Add your header files here(one file per line), please SORT in alphabetical order for future maintenance!
SET(${this_target}_HEADER_FILES
#   ...
    )



## section: precompiled header  
#ADD_MSVC_PRECOMPILED_HEADER("precompiled.h" "precompiled.cpp" MySources)
#ADD_LIBRARY(MyLibrary ${MySources})

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${this_target}_HEADER_FILES
                            PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE)
LIST(APPEND ${this_target}_SOURCE_FILES ${${this_target}_HEADER_FILES})

## section: add definitions
#   add prefix -D. example> -DSHP
#  - DO NOT add  the following definitions(already defined in ${OSP_DEFINITIONS}:
#   -DSHP, -DWIN32, -D_WINDOWS, -D_DEBUG, -D_USRDLL, -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
ADD_DEFINITIONS(
    -D_CONSOLE
    -DWIN32
    -D_PROJECT_1
    -DNDEBUG
    )

## section: add target

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${this_target} ${${this_target}_SOURCE_FILES})

## section: add dependency
# dependency determines overall build order.
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(${this_target} 
    ws2_32.lib
    zdll.lib
    $(BOOST_LIB)/libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-1_61.lib
    $(OPENSSL)/lib/libeay32.lib
    $(OPENSSL)/lib/ssleay32.lib
    )

## section: set link libraries
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${this_target}
        ws2_32.lib
    zdll.lib
    $(BOOST_LIB)/libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-1_61.lib
    $(OPENSSL)/lib/libeay32.lib
    $(OPENSSL)/lib/ssleay32.lib
        )
```

After renaming this file to Makefile1 and entering `make -f Makefile-1`
I get

> Makefile.1:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Consider cmake-gui

Answer (score 1):

#### make != CMake

[CMake](https://cmake.org/) is a build system that generates code for other build systems (such as `make` or VS projects). The tool you used emits CMake code, which must be interpreted by CMake. To build the project (assuming the tool was successful), you can first run CMake with the `make` generator, and then run `make` on the generated makefile.

Comment: What do I have to do with file generated by the tool to use `cmake`?